# Using 12.04 after support has finished

Tags: 12.04

I upgraded to 14.04 but for reasons unknown to me it doesn't work as smooth as 12.04 and I downgraded back to the older version. I'm sure this is a vague description, but I'm so satisfied with 12.04 that the upgrade seems unnecessary to me.
On the other hand, Lubuntu 14.04 works perfectly, but it is not my flavor of Ubuntu, so I want to know how much of a risk will be using an unsupported version in the future. Is it really comparable to Windows XP? Thanks.

Roberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 is a Long Term Support (LTS) version, which means that it is going to be supported for 5 years after the initial release based on [Ubuntu policies](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack). So, you should expect to be fine until some time in 2017. After that, indeed, you will be better off upgrading to another LTS release (14.04 is the current LTS, the next one should be 16.04).

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No, I will explain.
Unsupported versions don't receive updates that could be necessary to work safely. Recently the bash was updated on all Ubuntu 14.4 and 14.10, the outdated bash have vulnerability problems that were solved with upgrade. However you can continue using unsupported version, as long you be aware what you need to maintain your system safe and working well.

Answer (score 0):

I short you wont get any security update for all system software. for example, bash shell(default shell in your terminal), Firefox, Rhythmbox etc. will not get update.
Other software which you installed manually along with PPA will get updates.
NOTE: *its dangerous to use outdated software*. Recently, bash had a vulnerability called **shellshock**, which did not got update for old Ubuntu versions. You may get hacked. *Its always better to use updated version*.